# Application to create videos

Tags: video, application

I'm a new user of Ubuntu gnome, and I'm looking for a specific application. In different videos from youtube.com, I would like to select samples from several videos to create one. For example, amongst video_1, video_2, video_3, ...., video_n, I would like to be able to take the time interval 1 from the video_1, plus the time interval 2 from the video_2, plus ....,Plus the time interval n of the video_n for a single video. Could anyone be able to suggest me such application from Ubuntu I could use to do that (and how to do that, if possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this question fits an opinion-based question, which is not allowed here, but you could use `kdenlive` for this purpose:

## Kdenlive

---

[image: KdenliveScreenshot]

> Kdenlive is a non-linear video editing suite, which supports DV, HDV and many more formats. Its main features are: * Guides and marker for organizing timelines * Copy and paste support for clips, effects and transitions * Real time changes * FireWire and Video4Linux capture * Screen grabbing * Exporting to any by FFMPEG supported format

---

There are many other editors, like `lightworks`, `pitivi`, amongst others you can browse through the Ubuntu Software Center. I just recommended `kdenlive` because it's the one I've used before and it's pretty easy to do small trimming work with it.